# Pass variable to component template

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create a Vue.js component existing of some input fields. This means that the component template must accept name for the inputs.

Let's say I have the template:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" name="VARIABLE">
</template>
```

and I call that component with

```
<component-input></component-input>
```

How do my component-input define the value of VARIABLE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this

```js
Vue.component('input-component', {
  template: '<input type="text" :name="inputName">',
  props: {
   inputName: String   
  }
})
```

```html
<input-component input-name="someName"></input-component>
```

The point to your question is to use [`props`](https://vuejs.org/api/#props). Hope to help you.

Comment: that works for plain content. how to pass "html" content , so instead of `someName` we had i.e. `<span col="Rd">someName</span>`?

Comment: @T.Todua Child component is better for that. If you really want to insert html content, try `v-html="propHtml"`

Answer (score 3):

I got it:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" name="{{name}}">
</template>
```

-

```
<component-input name="demo"></component-input>
```

-

```
var component = Vue.extend({
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This has changed now I believe, and will invoke a compile-time error, as attributes on elements should reference `.model` instead.